# Html, C#, ASP.NET How can i repeat the contents in div tag containing labels to display all records from database?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am able to get values of user profile from database, and I want to display each record in a div tag that contains Labels. So in one page I want to show 10 records. I am able to show only one record as of now and hard coding 10 types of label tags seems wrong. Can anyone please guide me as to what I should do? I am able to get values from Db with c#, and I have the div tag with labels in aspx page. I just don't know how to loop the div tag.

My ASPX Page, div tag contains the below code:

```
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=" Driver Name:  "></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" ></asp:Label><br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Driver Car:  "></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server"></asp:Label><br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Car Number:  "></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server"></asp:Label><br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text="Rating:  " ></asp:Label>
```

My .CS file:

```
 using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionStringn))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select drivername,carname,carnumber,driverphoto from driver"))
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                try
                {
                    SqlDataAdapter dataAdapt = new SqlDataAdapter();
                    dataAdapt.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    dataAdapt.Fill(dt);
                    if (dt != null)
                    {
                        int i = dt.Rows.Count;
                        for ( a = 0; a <= i; a++)
                        {
                            Label2.Text=dt.Rows[a]["drivername"].ToString();
                            Label4.Text= dt.Rows[a]["carname"].ToString();
                            Label6.Text=dt.Rows[a]["carnumber"].ToString();

                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Is there any specific requirement to show the labels in every single row? You can achieve this using GridView control.

Comment: @SelvaTS I have used grid view in my website to show other data , but in this case i want to have data like a photo of the person and beside it his details and the ability to rate the person but in grid view it is like rows and columns .Is my requirement clear or should i like upload a picture of how i want the data to be displayed?Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should use a Control with a layout. Options are GridView , ListView etc.

Check out this link http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Dynamically-create-DataTable-and-bind-to-GridView-in-ASPNet.aspx

Comment: I saw your comment. The way the data is shown weighs heavily on the `<ItemTemplate>` Use that to give your self the look. Let the control do the work of binding the data.

Comment: thank you ,i will try to implement the editable items and other data where data has to be shown ,using ItemTemplate

Answer (score 0):

You can use GridView, DataList or Repeater. Because you want just to repeat div with labels in it, I'll use Repeater.

ASPX Page:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
 <ItemTemplate>
   <div>
     <asp:Label ID="lblDriverName" runat="server" Text='<%# string.Format("Driver Name:{0}", Eval("drivername")) %>' />
     <asp:Label ID="lblDriverCar" runat="server" Text='<%# string.Format("Driver Car:{0}", Eval("carname")) %>' />
     <asp:Label ID="lblCarNumber" runat="server" Text='<%# string.Format("Car Number:{0}", Eval("carnumber")) %>' />
   </div>
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

CS File:

```
private DataTable FillRepeater()
{
  using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionStringn))
  {
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select drivername,carname,carnumber,driverphoto from driver"))
    {
      cmd.Connection = con;
      try
      {
         DataTable dt = new DataTable();
         SqlDataAdapter dataAdapt = new SqlDataAdapter();
         dataAdapt.SelectCommand = cmd;
         dataAdapt.Fill(dt);
         return dt;
      }
      catch(Exception)
      {
        throw;
      }
  }
}

// Now fill the repeater in Page_Load() or something else
Repeater1.DataSource = FillRepeater();
Repeater1.DataBind();
```

For Gridwiew or DataList is the same thing, just set an ItemTemplate, a DataSource and DataBind the control.